# Айфоны. Проблема со скроллом модальном окне

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Суть проблемы такова: есть модальное окно, которое по высоте не влазит в область видимости (корзина товаров, например) и, соответственно, требует скролл. При этом, при скролле модального окна, контент под ним скроллится не должен.

Во всех браузерах это было решено добавлением свойства `overflow: hidden` для тегов `body` и `html`. Кроме Safari на айфонах. По какой-то, не объяснимой для меня причине, он просто игнорирует это свойство.

Так же пытался решить эту проблему добавлением обёртки для всего контента и исполнением тех же махинаций, что и c `body` и `html`. Но возникла проблема с "протаскиванием" сайта при достижения краёв экрана и переносом фокуса на контент под модальным окном, что напрочь блокировало скролл.

Вопрос в следующем: Как намертво запретить в айфонах скролл контента под модальным окном?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

или

```
body {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

или поставьте высоту `100%` || `100vh`